# Problem applying `Angular Universal` to an existing 8.2 project

Tags: angular, angular-universal

We just recently updated our project to `Angular 8.2` and when I do

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject universal
```

I get

```
Client app universal not found.
```

and none of files mentioned in the guide are added or updated and the `package.json` only contains this addition

```
"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^8.1.1",
```

and the `build:ssr` and `serve:ssr` scripts are missing.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your application name with flag named `--clientProject` in your command.

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --yourApplicationName universal
```

You can find your application name in the `angular.json` file under `projects` object.

Comment: Please explain because I used the `--clientProject` flag as I stated in my question.

Comment: Yes, I am saying you need to replace `clientProject` in the command `.. --clientProject...` with your application name.

Comment: Oh, you mean the name I supply in the `--clientProject` flag needs to match with a name in the `angular.json` file's list of projects!

Comment: Once I do that, I how getting:-
`ERROR in error TS6053: File '.../src/src/main.server.ts' not found.`

Comment: In the file `tsconfig.server.json` the `files` array has `src/` on the `main.server.ts` entry. Removing this fixes the problem.